# How do c/c++ compilers know which line an error is on

Tags: c++, c, parsing

There is probably a very obvious answer to this, but I was wondering how the compiler knows which line of code my error is on.  In some cases it even knows the column.

The only way I can think to do this is to tokenize the input string into a 2D array. This would store [lines][tokens].

C/C++ could be tokenized into 1 long 1D array which would probably be more efficient. I am wondering what the usual parsing method would be that would keep line information.

Comment: Typically each token is assigned meta data indicating the filename, line and column that the token came from.

Comment: Further, when things like methods and functions are declared, metadata locating that declaration are stored with the function in the symbol table, so when a method or function is defined or called, and there's something wrong with it, the compiler can get the location of the declaration from the symbol table to display with the error.

Comment: Well, how do **you** know which line of code an error is on? If you can carefully describe the algorithm you use to associate an error with a piece of text, then you can write a program that implements that algorithm. That program is a compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

actually most of it is covered in [the dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).
Compilers do Lexing/Parsing i.e.: transforming the source code into a tree representation.
When doing so each keyword variable etc. is associated with a line and column number.

However during parsing the exact origin of the failure might get lost and the information might be off.

Comment: Lexing typically converts source code into a stream of token. It's the parsing stage that takes the token stream and generates an AST to represent the source code.

Comment: @Sean: Yeah you're actually right. The clang Lexer also does preprocessing for performance reasons. The important part is that, already during lexing the line/column information is actually gathered and usually kept for better error reporting.

Answer (score 3):

This is the first step in the long, complicated path towards "Engineering a Compiler" or [Compilers Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_construction)

The short answer to that is: there's a module called "front-end" that usually takes care of many phases:

1. Scanning
2. Parsing
3. IR generator
4. IR optimizer ...

The structure isn't fixed so each compiler will have its own set of modules but more or less the steps involved in the front-end processing are

**Scanning** - maps character streams into words (also ignores whitespaces/comments) or **tokens**

**Parsing** - this is where syntax and (some) semantic analysis take place and where syntax errors are reported

To make this up to you: the compiler knows the location of your error because when something doesn't fit into a structure called "abstract syntax tree" (i.e. it cannot be constructed) or doesn't follow any of the syntax-directed translation rules, well.. there's something wrong and the compiler indicates the location where this didn't happen. If there's a grammar error on just one word/token then even a precise column location can be returned since nothing matched a **terminal keyword**: a basic token like the **if** keyword in the C/C++ language.

If you want to know more about this topic my suggestion is to start with the classic academic approach of the ["Compiler Book" or "Dragon Book"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3a_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) and then, later on, possibly study an open-source front-end like [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)